# What is the URL to Create a New Document set

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a new Document Set called "New Hire" which every time a user clicks on Items/New/New Hiring Document Set a new document set is created....Note in most cases the user will not have a need to save the document to SharePoint.  They will typically make some changes and then print out the document set and give to the new hire.  There is no real need to save.

My issue is the users find the steps of doing Items/New/New Hiring Document Set not intuitive and give up...95% of the people attempt to click on the button "New Document" and of course that does not create the document set.

Is there a way I could find out the URL to this document set and then I would just make it a Quick Link ?  Any suggestions would be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just about creating a new document set..

Click new document set in the target location and copy the url to where you need it to go such as the side navigation bar.

Using some html and/or JS you can then place that code where you want and make it behave how you want such as making it pop up, or redirect the user from a button click, etc.

URL will look something like this:

```
http://<site>/_layouts/15/NewDocSet.aspx?List=<ListGUIDString>&&ContentTypeId=0x0120D5200046F6D724D05F4346862FFA6B7215E4A3&RootFolder=/<Subsites>/<Top Level of library>
```

List Guid is the ID of the list that it is to be made in.
Content Type ID is that of a Document Set
and Root Folder is where the document set is to be made (if it is to be buried down a couple levels or at root, etc.)